# Minimizing entries in a many to many hashtable

Tags: python, algorithm, many-to-many, hashtable

I've run into an interesting problem, where I need to make a many-to-many hash with a minimized number of entries. I'm working in python, so that comes in the form of a dictionary, but this problem would be equally applicable in any language.

The data initially comes in as input of one key to one entry (representing one link in the many-to-many relationship).

So like:

```
A-1, B-1, B-2, B-3, C-2, C-3
```

A simple way of handling the data would be linking them one to many:

```
A: 1
B: 1,2,3
C: 2,3
```

However the number of entries is the primary computational cost for a later process, as a file will need to be generated and sent over the internet for each entry (that is a whole other story), and there would most likely be thousands of entries in the one-to-many implementation.

Thus a more optimized hash would be:

```
[A, B]: 1
[B, C]: 2,3
```

This table would be discarded after use, so maintainability is not a concern, the only concern is the time-complexity of reducing the entries (the time it takes the algorithm to reduce the entries must not exceed the time the algorithm would save in reducing the entries from the baseline one-to-many table).

Now, I'm pretty sure that at least someone has faced this problem, this seems like a problem straight out of my Algorithms class in college. However, I'm having trouble finding applicable algorithms, as I can't find the right search terms. I'm about to take a crack at making an algorithm for this from scratch, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask around to see if people can't identify this as a problem commonly solved by a  modified [insert well-known algorithm here].

I personally think it's best to start by creating a one-to-many hash and then examining subsets of the values in each entry, creating an entry in the solution hash for the maximum identified set of shared values. But I'm unsure how to guarantee a smaller number of subsets than just the one-to-many baseline implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go back to your your unoptimised dictionary of letters to sets of numbers:

```
A: 1
B: 1,2,3
C: 2,3
```

There's a - in this case 2-branch - tree of refactoring steps you could do:

```
                       A:1  B:1,2,3  C:2,3
                      /                   \
           factor using set 2,3    factor using set 1
                    /                       \
           A:1 B:1 B,C:2,3            A,B:1 B:2,3 C:2,3
                  /                           \
         factor using set 1            factor using set 2,3
                /                               \
           A,B:1 B,C:2,3                   A,B:1 B,C:2,3
```

In this case at least, you arrive at the same result regardless of which factoring you do first, but I'm not sure if that would always be the case.

Doing an exhaustive exploration of the tree sounds expensive, so you might want to avoid that, but if we could pick the optimal path, or at least a likely-good path, it would be relatively low computational cost.  Rather than branching at random, my guy instinct is that it'd be faster and closer to optimal if you tried to make the largest-set factoring change possible at each point in the tree.  For example, considering the two-branch tree above, you'd prefer the initial 2,3 factoring over the initial 1 factoring in your tree, because 2,3 has the larger set of size two.  More dramatic refactoring suggest the number of refactorings before you get a stable result will be less.

What that amounts to is iterating the sets from largest towards smallest (it doesn't matter which order you iterate over same-length sets), looking for refactoring opportunities.

Much like a bubble-sort, after each refactoring the approach would be "I made a change; it's not stable yet; let's repeat".  Restart by iterating from second-longest sets towards shortest sets, checking for optimisation opportunities as you go.

(I'm not sure about python, but in general set comparisons can be expensive, you might want to maintain a value for each set that is the XOR of the hashed values in the set - that's easy and cheap to update if a few set elements are changed, and a trivial comparison can tell you large sets are unequal, saving comparison time; it won't tell you if sets are equal though: multiple sets could have the same XOR-of-hashes value).